Flow<PostgresAction.Insert>.onEach{}.collect() not running and blocking further commands from running for supabase realtime and kotlin android studio
I am working on a chatting app using Kotlin, XML, Android Studio and Supabase(for the back-end).
I am facing a problem with the real time feature so that I can handle real time messaging between users.
private suspend fun realtimeCheck(scope: CoroutineScope){
        try{
            println("here")
            channel = supabase.channel(chatRoomId)
            val dataFlow = channel.postgresChangeFlow<PostgresAction.Insert>(schema = "public"){
                table = "message"
            }
            println("here 2")
            dataFlow.onEach { change ->
                println("Reach in here $change")
                val stringifiedMessage = change.record.toString()
                val data = Json.decodeFromString<data.message>(stringifiedMessage)
                messageContainer.addMessage(data)
                runOnUiThread {
                    recyclerViewMessages.invalidate()
                }
            }.catch{e -> e.printStackTrace()}.collect()
            println("Data Flow: $dataFlow")
            println("after loop")
            channel.subscribe(blockUntilSubscribed = true)
            println(channel.status.value)
        }catch(e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(this@ChatScreen, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

This function deals with the real time aspect of supabase by creating a channel, and subscribing to it, the onEach{} code block is supposed to update the list of messages by adding the new message and then call .notifyItemInserted(messageList.size - 1) to update the RecyclerView so the user can see the new message in real time(be it a received message or sent).
My problem is that the dataFlow.onEach{}.collect() never actually executes even when an insert operation happens on Supabase(on the Supabase website or via the API in Kotlin) and blocks the functions after from running, so println("Data Flow: $dataFlow") and after never runs.
I tried using .launchIn(scope) but that only allowed execution to continue and reach the rest of the function.
That did allow me to see that the println(channel.status.value) line prints SUBSCRIBED. However I still did not get an output from the code block inside the .onEach{} block.

I have found out the solution and would like to share:
The problem was that my onResume() function was calling the realtimeCheck(this) function twice which caused undefined behavior.
